# PHP inserting error without explanation

Tags: php, mysql

im farely new to php coding. I have been using web pages to assist me in learning. But right now im stuck.

Im trying to insert a record into a table but im unable.
the php just produces the message `"error:"` but gives no further info. any assistance would be great.

P.S the conenction to the table is working fine, already checked i am able to read data, and obviously the username and password are for read and write rights...

```
  $sql="INSERT INTO users (email, username, password, full_name, company_name, active, active_until, start_date, remote_backup, local_backup)
VALUES
('".$register_email_address."','".$register_username."','".$register_password."','".$register_fullname."','".$register_company_name."','".$active."','".$active_until."','".$start_date."','".$remote_backup."','".$local_backup."'";
if (!mysqli_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
```

Comment: echo $sql; and try executing the query directly in MySQL. does this give you any error!

Comment: It should be noted that this is a VERY dangerous way to do an INSERT.  You are WIDE OPEN for SQL injection.

Comment: die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!mysqli_query($sql,$con))
```

The mysqli_query function takes the connection as the first argument, not the second.  You'll need to switch the order of the arguments.  You should also modify your php.ini file to enable error reporting + display errors - it'll tell you about this sort of thing.

Comment: this seems to have been a step in the right direction. I am just testing it now and correcting some values and il get back to you on that.

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously missing closing parenthesis here:

```
.$local_backup."')";
```

Also make sure that:

1. All data you try to insert is SQL injection safe.
2. Dates are in format that MySQL understands.
3. All data types are convertable (i.e. `$active` is probably int).

Comment: I did change it and put the ) there, and it did not help. Same problem still.

Comment: how do I go about making it injection safe? As I said. I am very new to php coding.

Answer (score 1):

you should use mysqli connection to get error

use

```
echo mysqli_error($con);
```